# Installing and Maintaining Percona Server in an WHM/CPanel Environment

Tags: mysql, cpanel, whm, percona

I have a VPS with Liquidweb, which currently uses a standard LAMP stack. I want to replace/supplement the installed version of MySQL with Percona, specifically to leverage XtraDB's advanced features. My initial request to their SysAdmins was they don't support that since its a nonstandard install.

My question is has anyone successfully run Percona in a WHM/Cpanel controlled environment? How did you install Percona? Did you have any problems? How do you maintain that installation? Were you able to have WHM "automatically" upgrade Percona, or at least prevent it from upgrading Percona down to MySQL? Is there a better way?

As a background, I am a software developer. I can run make, but managing a secure DB installation is beyond my scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ecommy.com/linux/install-percona-in-a-whm-cpanel-environment

also:

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/installing-percona-mysql-track-queries-per-user-table-access-volumes-103477.html

The install is pretty straight forward. The database upgrading will not be managed within WHM/cpanel, so you would need to use your own method to administer updates. You should be able to install Maria in about the same matter.

I would personally keep a close eye on the installed database when cpanel does an update, just to make sure that it doesn't do something crazy like kicking the Percona version out. But, it should work without too much fuss.